# QSlider работает как кнопка

Tags: python, pyqt5, gui, pygame, qmediaplayer

Я делаю музыкальный плеер с помощью *PyQy5* и *Pygame*, проблема в том,  что ползунок громкости работает как кнопка.

Проблема в том, что ползунок отключает звук в начале и больше он никак не изменяется, т.е. у него есть два положения **ON** и **OFF**.

Код дизайна:

```
from PyQt5 import QtCore, QtGui, QtWidgets
from os import system
import pygame
import subprocess

pygame.init()

class Ui_Dialog(object):
    def setupUi(self, Dialog):
        Dialog.setObjectName("Dialog")
        Dialog.resize(841, 439)
        Dialog.setAutoFillBackground(False)
        Dialog.setStyleSheet("QDialog{ \n"
"   backgraund-color: black\n"
"}\n"
"QPushButton1: hover{\n"
"   backgraund-color: silver;\n"
"   color: white\n"
"}\n"
"\n"
"\n"
"\n"
"\n"
"")
        
        self.progressBar = QtWidgets.QProgressBar(Dialog)
        self.progressBar.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(20, 270, 781, 23))
        self.progressBar.setProperty("value", 24)
        self.progressBar.setObjectName("progressBar")
        self.horizontalSlider = QtWidgets.QSlider(Dialog)
        self.horizontalSlider.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(20, 250, 741, 22))
        self.horizontalSlider.setOrientation(QtCore.Qt.Horizontal)
        self.horizontalSlider.setObjectName("horizontalSlider")
        self.verticalSlider = QtWidgets.QSlider(Dialog)
        self.verticalSlider.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(310, 80, 22, 160))
        self.verticalSlider.setOrientation(QtCore.Qt.Vertical)
        self.verticalSlider.setObjectName("verticalSlider")
        self.toolButton = QtWidgets.QToolButton(Dialog)
        self.toolButton.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(23, 1, 59, 19))
        self.toolButton.setObjectName("toolButton")
        self.pushButton = QtWidgets.QPushButton(Dialog)
        self.pushButton.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(150, 310, 59, 28))
        self.pushButton.setStyleSheet("QPushButton {\n"
"   backgraund-color: black;\n"
"}\n"
"\n"
"QPushButton:hover{\n"
"   backgraund-color: silver;\n"
"}")
        self.pushButton.setObjectName("pushButton")
        self.pushButton_2 = QtWidgets.QPushButton(Dialog)
        self.pushButton_2.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(20, 310, 59, 28))
        self.pushButton_2.setObjectName("pushButton_2")
        self.pushButton_3 = QtWidgets.QPushButton(Dialog)
        self.pushButton_3.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(85, 310, 59, 28))
        self.pushButton_3.setStyleSheet("QPushButton")
        self.pushButton_3.setObjectName("pushButton_3")
        self.toolButton_2 = QtWidgets.QToolButton(Dialog)
        self.toolButton_2.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(120, 1, 59, 19))
        self.toolButton_2.setObjectName("toolButton_2")
        self.graphicsView = QtWidgets.QGraphicsView(Dialog)
        self.graphicsView.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(20, 50, 256, 192))
        self.graphicsView.setObjectName("graphicsView")
        self.treeView = QtWidgets.QTreeView(Dialog)
        self.treeView.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(500, 50, 256, 192))
        self.treeView.setObjectName("treeView")
        self.lcdNumber = QtWidgets.QLCDNumber(Dialog)
        self.lcdNumber.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(660, 310, 91, 31))
        self.lcdNumber.setObjectName("lcdNumber")
        self.textBrowser = QtWidgets.QTextBrowser(Dialog)
        self.textBrowser.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(230, 310, 421, 31))
        self.textBrowser.setObjectName("textBrowser")

        self.retranslateUi(Dialog)
        QtCore.QMetaObject.connectSlotsByName(Dialog)

    def retranslateUi(self, Dialog):
        _translate = QtCore.QCoreApplication.translate
        Dialog.setWindowTitle(_translate("Dialog", "Dialog"))
        self.toolButton.setToolTip(_translate("Dialog", "<html><head/><body><p>What this?</p><p><br/></p></body></html>"))
        self.toolButton.setText(_translate("Dialog", "settings"))
        self.pushButton.setText(_translate("Dialog", ">"))
        self.pushButton_2.setText(_translate("Dialog", "<"))
        self.pushButton_3.setText(_translate("Dialog", "pause"))
        self.toolButton_2.setToolTip(_translate("Dialog", "<html><head/><body><p>Opened your file</p></body></html>"))
        self.toolButton_2.setText(_translate("Dialog", "open file"))
```

код:

```
    import sys
from PyQt5 import QtWidgets
import lol
from tkinter import filedialog
from tkinter import *
import os
import os.path
import subprocess
import pygame

class ExampleApp(QtWidgets.QMainWindow, lol.Ui_Dialog):
    def __init__(self):
        # Это здесь нужно для доступа к переменным, методам
        # и т.д. в файле design.py
        super().__init__()
        self.setupUi(self)
        self.toolButton_2.clicked.connect(open)
        self.verticalSlider.valueChanged[int].connect(intr)
  # Это нужно для инициализации нашего дизайн

def main():
    app = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)  # Новый экземпляр QApplication
    window = ExampleApp()  # Создаём объект класса ExampleApp
    window.show()  # Показываем окно
    app.exec_()  # и запускаем приложение


def open():
   folder_selected = pygame.mixer.music.load(filedialog.askopenfilename())
   pygame.mixer.music.play()
 
def intr(open):
   pygame.mixer.music.set_volume(open)


if __name__ == '__main__':
   main()
```

Помогите пожалуйста, звук должен изменяться плавно. 
Заранее всем спасибо.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Я не смог воспроизвести ваш пример, но я покажу вам один вариант, как бы я сделал музыкальный плеер с помощью **PyQt5**.

Я думаю, что вам не сложно будет применить его в своем коде.

**Qt Multimedia** является важным модулем, который предоставляет богатый набор типов QML 
и классов C++ для обработки мультимедийного контента. 
Он также предоставляет необходимые API для доступа к функциям камеры и радио.

```
import sys
from PyQt5.Qt import QUrl, Qt
from PyQt5.QtMultimedia import QMediaPlayer, QMediaContent
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import QApplication, QWidget, QSlider, QPushButton, QGridLayout


class Demo(QWidget):
    def __init__(self):
        super(Demo, self).__init__()

        self.player = QMediaPlayer(self)

        self.volumeslider = QSlider(Qt.Horizontal)
        self.volumeslider.setFocusPolicy(Qt.NoFocus)
        self.volumeslider.valueChanged[int].connect(self.change_volume)
        self.volumeslider.setValue(100)
        self.volume = self.volumeslider.value()

        play_btn  = QPushButton('Play')   
        play_btn.clicked.connect(self.playMedia)
        pause_btn = QPushButton('Pause') 
        pause_btn.clicked.connect(self.pauseMedia)
        stop_btn  = QPushButton('Stop')  
        stop_btn.clicked.connect(self.stopMedia)

        layout = QGridLayout(self)
        layout.addWidget(play_btn, 0, 0)
        layout.addWidget(pause_btn, 0, 1)
        layout.addWidget(stop_btn, 0, 2)
        layout.addWidget(self.volumeslider, 1, 0, 1, 3)

        self.player.setMedia(QMediaContent(QUrl('http://rfm-live-mp3-64.scdn.arkena.com/rfm.mp3'))) 

        self.player.setVolume(self.volume) 
        self.player.play()        

    def change_volume(self, value):
        self.player.setVolume(value)

    def playMedia(self):
        self.player.play()  

    def pauseMedia(self):
        self.player.pause()        

    def stopMedia(self):
        self.player.stop()  


if __name__ == '__main__':
    app = QApplication(sys.argv)
    demo = Demo()
    demo.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]